# Word for "resisant to accept explanation"

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a word to describe someone who is "resistant to accept an explanation".

> - Learner: Woah, I just don't understand how the tides work, it's so complicated!
> - Teacher: <provides explanation in simple terms, at a level that the learner could certainly understand.>
> - Learner: Oh it all sounds so complicated - I could never understand all that science stuff, hah!

In this case, the learner would clearly understand the explanation, but it almost resistant, or unwilling to accept what they've just been told. Is there a word for that? Is "wilful ignorance" the best option?

Comment: “Willful ignorance” is technically correct, but its legal connotations of criminal or negligent wrong doing makes me dislike it. No one has a duty to like physical science.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest '[obstinate](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/obstinate)':

> - firmly or stubbornly adhering to one's purpose, opinion, etc.; **not yielding to argument, persuasion, or entreaty**.
> - characterized by inflexible persistence or an unyielding attitude; inflexibly persisted in or carried out.

This says nothing about a potential lack of intelligence, but indicates a quality of a person whose mind is made up in advance not to want to learn or broaden their horizon (at a particular moment, and which could be for a number of reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nuance of what you want to say, you might consider:

- Pig ignorant
- Stubborn
- Unteachable
- Obtuse
- Headstrong
- Bloody-minded
- Wilful
- Single-minded

Some of these might imply that they think they know better than you, others that they are just reluctant to change. You could look these up in a dictionary or similar resource.

Comment: No, never.

If the learner clearly understands then pretty-much your best option is the learner being "in denial" or simply "dishonest" and even then, "best" by no means matches "good." 

For instance, none of Astralbee's suggestions,  nor anything like them, closely matches the exposition.